# Pick multiple images from gallery and show in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

my app requires to select multiple images from gallery and to show them in a horizontal Recycler View. I know how to do when I use only ImageView but in that case I'm struggling how to do it. After that I wiill send images to server.
I have created my adapter for recycler view as:

```
public class HorizontalRecyclerView extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HorizontalRecyclerView.HorizontalViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<Photos> photos;

    public HorizontalRecyclerView(ArrayList<Photos> photos) {
        this.photos = photos;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public HorizontalViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int i) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_image, parent, false);
        return new HorizontalViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull HorizontalViewHolder horizontalViewHolder, int position) {
        Photos imgs = photos.get(position);
        Picasso.get()
                .load(imgs.getUri())
                .into(horizontalViewHolder.mImageRecyclerView);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return photos.size();
    }

    public class HorizontalViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ImageView mImageRecyclerView;

        public HorizontalViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mImageRecyclerView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgLoader);
        }
    }
}
```

I did also a model for selecting pictures and Uri:

```
public class Photos {
    String name;
    Uri uri;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Uri getUri() {
        return uri;
    }

    public void setUri(Uri uri) {
        this.uri = uri;
    }
}
```

I'm my activity I need to call the recycler view, but is not showing me anything. I need some help how to in the right way. My activity code is, only onActivityResult part:

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        try {
            // When an image is picked
            if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_MULTIPLE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
                // get the image from data
                String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
                imagesEncodedList = new ArrayList<>();
                if (data.getData() != null) {
                    Uri mImageUri = data.getData();

                    // Get the cursor
                    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(mImageUri, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                    // Move to first row
                    assert cursor != null;
                    cursor.moveToFirst();

                    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                    imageEncoded = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                    cursor.close();

                    /*Bitmap mBitmap;
                    BitmapFactory.Options bitmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                    mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath(), bitmapOptions);
                    file = savebitmap(mBitmap);*/

                    ArrayList<Uri> mArrayUri = new ArrayList<>();
                    mArrayUri.add(mImageUri);
                    horizontalRecyclerView = new HorizontalRecyclerView(photos);
                    imagesRecyclerView.setAdapter(horizontalRecyclerView);
                    horizontalRecyclerView.notifyDataSetChanged();
                } else {
                    if (data.getClipData() != null) {
                        ClipData mClipData = data.getClipData();
                        ArrayList<Uri> mArrayUri = new ArrayList<>();
                        for (int i = 0; i < mClipData.getItemCount(); i++) {
                            ClipData.Item item = mClipData.getItemAt(i);
                            Uri uri = item.getUri();
                            mArrayUri.add(uri);

                            // Get the cursor
                            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                            // Move to first row
                            assert cursor != null;
                            cursor.moveToFirst();

                            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                            imageEncoded  = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                            imagesEncodedList.add(imageEncoded);
                            cursor.close();

                            /*Bitmap mMultipleBitmap;
                            BitmapFactory.Options bo = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                            mMultipleBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath(), bo);
                            file = savebitmap(mMultipleBitmap);*/

                            horizontalRecyclerView = new HorizontalRecyclerView(photos);
                            imagesRecyclerView.setAdapter(horizontalRecyclerView);
                            horizontalRecyclerView.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                        Log.v("LOG_TAG", "Selected Images" + mArrayUri.size());
                    }
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "You haven't picked Image", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you setting a value to array photos before lines:  horizontalRecyclerView = new HorizontalRecyclerView(photos);?

Answer (score 0):

set the `layout-manager` in your code

```
LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
horizontalRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
```

Comment: Its not working, crashed:
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager)' on a null object reference

Answer (score 0):

Think about the RecyclerView can show empty Collection. If you define in your layout RecyclerView (wrap_content, wrap_content) then in an empty scenario the View will be 0dp x 0dp and is valid.

The good thing about that is always you got an RecyclerView setted, Adapter initialized and never got a NullPointerExceptions.

You can have in Activity.onCreate():

```
imagesRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.someId);
horizontalAdapter = new HorizontalAdapter();
imagesRecyclerView.setAdapter(horizontalRecyclerView);
imagesRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));
```

Please note I changed the name of Adapter because "horizontalRecyclerView" != RecyclerView. And "horizontalAdapter" == Adapter.

Comment: I want to know how to set the file path for images, my question is: I have to do this in adapter or in my activity?

Comment: Logic to show TextView, ImageView and everything have relation to Presentation logic must be inside the Adapter.

Maybe you can use Picasso to show images.

Comment: Oh sorry, yes, then your Adapter have correct responsibility division! Very good!